# Make Main HWND Receive 2nd Degree Child Events

Tags: winapi

I have a WinAPI button control who's parent is a static control (and not the main HWND). When the button is clicked the main HWND doesn't receive an event. *Note the static control is a child of the main HWND.

From what I understand, this is as designed because the Static control would be receiving the event. Correct me if I am wrong though.

Is there any way to make the main HWND receive the `BN_CLICKED` event? Maybe I can setup the button to dispatch its events to the main HWND? *Note: making the button a direct child of the main HWND is not the best solution as the static control is pretty much a container for this button and many others.

Comment: You can have the intermediate static control forward the message to the main window.

Comment: STATIC controls **visually** group other controls. This is not done using any parent/child-relationships, but by positioning the controls inside the STATIC control.

Comment: @IInspectable: but the grouped controls have to be children of the `STATIC` control. It can't group another window's child controls. And it doesn't make sense to merely position controls over the `STATIC` without making them actual children of the `STATIC` control.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You are right, I was thinking of [GroupBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368766.aspx) controls instead of a [Static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769.aspx) control.

Comment: @IInspectable: controls displayed inside a GroupBox still have to be children of the GroupBox.  That is how it knows which controls to group together.

Comment: Do they have to be children of a `BS_GROUPBOX` control (as opposed to a .net GroupBox as linked)? I currently have mine as children, but none of the common dialogs seem to (they rely purely on `WS_GROUP` machinery).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The *GroupBox* doesn't know about it's "child" controls. That's why you still have to specify the `WS_GROUP` window style, even if controls appear to be inside a *GroupBox* control. (Yes, I meant to link to the Windows API documentation for [Group Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775947.aspx#group_boxes)).

Comment: @JakeM to elaborate on what Raymond means, you use subclassing with `SetWindowSubclass()` and friends to catch `WM_COMMAND` and `WM_NOTIFY` messages and forward them to the correct window. You can even abstract that all into a function that all parent windows call so you can keep your event handlers in one place

Comment: @IInspectable: AFAIK, `WS_GROUP` does not *visually* group controls together, it only *logically* groups them, for purposes of controlling the input focus. *Visual* grouping is done by making the controls be children of a common parent container.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Not in the Windows API, though. The plain Common Controls implementation has no way to group controls. `BS_GROUPBOX` is the only way to visually group controls. The application still has to provide the `WS_GROUP` style to logically group them, to match the visuals.

Comment: @IInspectable: Whether or not `WS_GROUP` is used, that doesn't change the fact that the controls still have to be children of the same parent control in order to be grouped *visually*.  But whatever, we've gotten WAY off-track of the original question.  What andlabs said about subclassing is the correct solution for the question at hand.

Comment: I don't think you two are disagreeing with each other about the purpose of `WS_GROUP` or `BS_GROUPBOX`, but you do seem to disagree on what "visually grouped" means, and I guess it is confusing because `BS_GROUPBOX` isn't the *only* way to group related controls together, it's just *one* way to (differing the amount of spacing is another way to), and having different parents can (but does not have to) result in different background colors, which gives the visual effect of being unrelated. But yes, this debate is derailing :)

Comment: (In fact, I think what IInspectable originally referred to is something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC725291.png), where two static controls are used to draw text and a line. [GNOME prefers using labels and spacing as opposed to lines for its groupboxes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1HTEl.png), though the implementation is still done using its equivalent of a groupbox control.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both Raymond Chen and andlabs stated in comments, you need to subclass the Static control to intercept `WM_COMMAND`/`WM_NOTIFY` messages being sent to it by its child button.  The subclass procedure can then handle the messages, forward them to other `HWNDs`, etc as needed.